# Renaming files with batch

Tags: batch, batch-file, rename

Is it possible to write a .bat-file that changes the names of all the files in a folder?
 For example: if I have a bunch of jpegs in a folder that have random names:

```
File1.jpg
ScreendumpA2.jpg
Test13.jpg
```

And I would like to change them to something like this:

```
Picture001.jpg
Picture002.jpg
Picture003.jpg
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Windows, you can do this without a batch file.  Select all of the files, press <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename the first one and it will automatically rename the others.

Using your example:  Select All -> <kbd>F2</kbd> -> type 'Picture' -> <kbd>Enter</kbd> would give you Picture (1).jpg, Picture (2).jpg, Picture (3).jpg...etc.

Comment: Thanks Kazoni
This way, the file names can only end with (#). And i would really like to be able to choose for instance 001-###.